# How can I configure Installer for 32Bit and 64Bit JRE as well?

Tags: 64-bit, installation, install4j, 32-bit

Is there a possibility to configure an Installer (Install4J 8.0.4) which runs under 32bit and 64bit JRE as well?
At the moment, I have configured two media files in the Install4J project, so
that I get two Installer one for 32bit und another one for 64 bit JRE Support.

And the second question is, how can I configure that two different installers can access the same named data files? That doesn't work for me even though I use different compiler variables for naming the installer and the directory for the data files?

[Install4J Editor - Installer data files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HED4T.png)

[Install4J Editor - Media file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5iYj.png)

Answer (score 0):

32-bit executables work on 64-bit Windows installations as well, so you can choose to distribute 32-bit media files only.

For dedicated 32-bit and 64-bit support, you need to separate media files, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit, there is no way to combine them into a single one.

As for the media file names (please ask separate question on stackoverflow), you have to use the same URL for all media files, and not include the media file name in it.